# SQL: Select last 5 unique results from database?

Tags: php, mysql, unique

Please, I would like the best way to return  the last 5 unique results from my database. So far I am using the following code but obviously it can return some results that are duplicate values.

Column0 is row ID's and are the unique numeric keys. Column1 values need to be unique and column2 can and will return some duplicate values.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `mydb`
WHERE field = 'value' 
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 5") ;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
 { 
 $var = $row['column1'];
 $var2 = $row['column2'];
 }

echo $var;
echo $var2;
echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: Yes thanks but I am struggling to find examples of the right syntax. Where to put the DISTINCT and anything thing else I need to change because I am using it. If that makes sense.

Comment: I wanted to give a generic example but in my actual code the ID's are unique numeric keys but some of the fields in one of columns can be the same and I only want one of each of those.

Comment: starting to sound like a poorly normalises schema

Comment: what's a " poorly normalises schema"? i am new to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
select distinct *
FROM `mydb`
WHERE field = 'value' 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If `id` is different on each row and you want the *rest* of the columns to be distinct:

```
select <all columns but id>
FROM `mydb`
WHERE field = 'value' 
group by <all columns but id>
ORDER BY min(id) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

For the situation where you want column 2 to have unique values, then use `group by`:

```
select *
FROM `mydb`
WHERE field = 'value' 
group by column2
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Getting SQL error. No results. Column2 my have duplicate values. My bad. I Need just column1 to have only unique values. Column2 can have the same values and will. Row ID's (Column0) will be unique anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sincerely but DISTINCT worked like below. I worked it out from your responses.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT column
    FROM `mydb`
    WHERE field = 'value' 
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 5") ;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
     { 
     $var = $row['column'];
     }

    echo $var;
    echo "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the rest of columns and mantain your distinct.

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT t.column, t.*
FROM 
  `mydb` AS t
WHERE 
  t.field = 'value' 
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Not tried this but it looks like it may work. I have added my own answer that I was able to test and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE field = 'value'
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 5
```

When there are multiple rows with the same `column1` value, this will select one of them arbitrarily. If you need the one with the highest ID, use this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mydb t1
JOIN (SELECT column1, max(ID) ID
      FROM mydb
      GROUP BY column1) t2
USING (column1, ID)
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 5
```